# any direct method to Access dynamic url in post method

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-views

in views.py

```
class ProcessMessage(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'chat/chat.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj=None
        if id is not None:
            obj= User.objects.get(pk=id)

        return obj

    def get(self, request, pk=None,*args, **kwargs):

        obj=self.get_object()
        print(obj,pk)
        super(ProcessMessage, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': ChatForm()})

   def post(self, request, pk=None,*args, **kwargs):
        obj=self.get_object()
        pk=pk
        print(pk)
        print('obj is',obj)
        form = ChatForm(data=request.POST)

        # log = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

        # print('post from index')
        if form.is_valid():
         //////something////
```

in urls.py

```
app_name = 'chatbot'
urlpatterns = [
    path('demo', views.ProcessMessage.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<uuid:pk>/demo', views.ProcessMessage.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

I am getting the value of obj and pk inside `get` method but I want those value inside `post` method also(getting value None currently)

I need id/pk from URL in def Post method to get user information(no I don't want to use request.user)

Comment: `request.POST.get('pk')` but obviously you need something (form/JS) to send `PK` in POST request.

Comment: I m also thinking the same but I am hoping for some direct method if possible

Comment: `self.kwargs.get('pk')` should work the same way for GET and POST requests. Please show your template.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried it, showing the value None

Comment: What line shows the value `None`? Please [edit] the question and include the template as I asked.

Comment: @Alasdair I m not providing URL through the template, I am providing the url directly example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/45058ff4-26ca-4077-a5c7-3f4e881c9890/demo

Comment: and I m hoping to get that value 45058ff4-26ca-4077-a5c7-3f4e881c9890 in my post method

Comment: i m getting none value in ```def post(self, request, pk=None,*args, **kwargs):
        obj=self.get_object()
        pk=pk
        print(pk)
        print('obj is',obj)```

Comment: `self.kwargs.get('pk')` should work. If it returns `None` then you are accessing a URL that does not have `pk` in the kwargs. Personally, I would remove `pk` from `def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):` and always fetch it from `self.kwargs`, but I don't think that's the issue here. If you won't trust me and show the template when I ask for it, then I can't help you debug the problem. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: added the template please have a look

Comment: @Alasdair have a look I edited it with template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template shows that you are submitting the form to a URL without a pk:

```
{% url 'chat:index' %}
```

You should include the pk when reversing the URL, e.g.

```
{% url 'chat:index' pk %}
```

You'll need to include the pk in the template context, e.g.

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': ChatForm(), 'pk': pk})
```

I see that you are using the same view `ProcessMessage` for `/demo/` and `/<pk>/demo/`. I would recommend using a different view for both URLs, I think it would help avoid issues like this.